# How access to template ref in conditional rendering using Composition API?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I need access to DOM-element (set focus) which rendering through `v-if` condition:

```html
<template>
    <input
        v-if="isInputShow"
        ref="input"
    >
    <button
        v-else
        @click="showInput"
    >Show input</button>
</template>
```

```js
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {
    setup() {
        const isInputShow = ref(false)
        const input = ref(null)

        const showInput = () => {
            if(!isInputShow.value) {
                isInputShow.value = true
                console.log(input.value) //null
            }
        }
        
        return{
            input,
            isInputShow,
            showInput
        }
    }
}
```

`onMounted` hook doesn't work (conditional rendering).
Change `v-if` condition on `v-show` doesn't work (need to hide another element).
Maybe I should use `reactive()` instead of `ref()`? But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can watch the input ref, it could give a more concise solution:

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```
<script setup>
import { watch, ref } from 'vue'

const isInputShow = ref(false)
const input = ref(null)

watch(input, input => {
    // if you show/hide the input with v-if, check it's not null
    input && console.log(input);
});

</script>

<template>
    <input
        v-if="isInputShow"
        ref="input"
    >
    <button
        v-else
        @click="isInputShow = true"
    >Show input</button>
</template>
```

As mentioned by yoduh you could use `nextTick()` also. But it returns a promise so `async/await` would give a more clean solution imho:

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```
<script setup>
import { nextTick, ref } from 'vue'

const isInputShow = ref(false)
const input = ref(null)

const showInput = async () => {
    if(!isInputShow.value) {
        isInputShow.value = true
        await nextTick();
        console.log(input.value) 
    }
}
</script>

<template>
    <input
        v-if="isInputShow"
        ref="input"
    >
    <button
        v-else
        @click="showInput"
    >Show input</button>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution with `watch` is work for me. Why `nextTick` doesn’t work for me was explained under yoduh’s post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the next DOM update to be able to access the ref.  This can be asynchronously achieved with [nextTick](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick)

```js
import { nextTick, ref } from 'vue'
...
const showInput = () => {
    if(!isInputShow.value) {
        isInputShow.value = true
        nextTick(() => {
            console.log(input.value)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Grrr... It seems I simplified the example too much))
Your solution works as expected. But in a real example it didn’t work for me. And then it dawned on me - `v-if/v-else` rendering through `transition` delay...))
Thanks anyway. Saved it in my recipe box.